# GRAILS plugin error

Tags: grails-plugin

All,

I am trying to test my grails app using Hudson. I have in grails I will run the command of test-app -unit and will recieve the following message:

> Running script /home/test/grails-1.1.1/scripts/TestApp.groovy
> Environment set to test
>
> Plugin [hibernate-1.1.1] not
> installed, resolving..
>
> Reading remote plugin list ...
>
> Error reading remote plugin list
> [Connection timed out], building
> locally...
>
> Unable to list plugins, please check
> you have a valid internet connection:
> Connection timed  out
>
> Reading remote plugin list ... Error
> reading remote plugin list [Connection
> timed out], building locally...
>
> Unable to list plugins, please check
> you have a valid internet connection:
> Connection timed out
>
> Plugin 'hibernate' was not found in
> repository. If it is not stored in a
> configured repository you will need to
> install it manually. Type 'grails
> list-plugins' to find out what plugins
> are available. Finished: FAILURE

I believe the reason for this is that I do not have access to an external network on the server. If I do a list-plugins there is no returns it just times out.
I also beleive that this is a grails issue not a hudson issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is the following:

1. navigate to the `/path/to/hudson/Jobs/JOBNAME/`
2. run - `grails install-plugin /location/to/grails-1.1.1/plugins/grails-hibernate-1.1.1.zip`

This will install the hibernate plugin for the specific job. This workaround can also be used for other plugins needed.

This has been tested in hudson.

Answer (score 1):

Grails is going to need the Internet somehow to get plugin information. What you might be able to do is get Grails installed on a machine that does have access, get all of the plugins you need (i.e. by running what Hudson would normally run, `test-app` or whatever), and then copy over the entire grails installation to `$GRAILS_HOME` on your Hudson machine.

I can't say I've ever tried this, but it seems like it should work.